# How to work with google.protobuf.timestamp and cassandra

Tags: go, cassandra, protocol-buffers

I'm using "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto" to define timestamp type in golang struct:

```
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";    
message User {
    string id = 1; 
    ...
    google.protobuf.Timestamp created_at = 12;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp updated_at = 13;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp last_login = 14;
}
```

and when insert to cassandra using cqlx:

```
req.CreatedAt = ptypes.TimestampNow()
// I also try with:
// req.CreatedAt = &timestamp.Timestamp{Seconds: time.Now().Unix(), Nanos: int32(time.Now().Nanosecond())}
```

I always get this error message: can not marshal timestamp.Timestamp into timestamp. Anyone have work with this please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into the same thing last week. You need to use [ptypes](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/ptypes/timestamp.go#L79)

```
ts, err := ptypes.Timestamp(result.GetDateDone())
if err != nil {
    ts = time.Now().UTC()
}
err = trr.cassandra.Execute(query,
    result.TaskID,
    result.TaskName,
    result.Status,
    result.Result,
    ts,
    result.Traceback,
    result.Children,
)
```

Here result is a proto message defined by:

```
message TaskResult {
    string TaskID = 1;
    string TaskName = 2;
    string Status = 3;
    bytes Result = 4;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp DateDone = 5;
    bytes Traceback = 6;
    bytes Children = 7;
}
```

And the column family has a field

```
date_done timestamp,
```

Comment: `ptypes.Timestamp()` return a `time.Time` while `google.protobuf.Timestamp` generated `*timestamp.Timestamp` as field's data type, and the field created_at in my cassandra is in type timestamp. Could you provide more details about data type in proto file?

Comment: Edited for clarity - hopefully.